# Resize UIScrollView that is inside a view

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I'm having a problem where I cannot increase the height of my UIScrollView.  The UIScrollView lies inside of a UIView. Here is an image depicting my xib setup:

[image: xib picture]

Link in case picture does not appear: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ffMHR.jpg

The UIScrollView I'm having troubles with is called "Scroll View-background" in the picture. Is there something beyond changing the height of the UIScrollView's contentSize attribute that I need to do in order for its height to change? Do I need to adjust some attributes of its superview?

Appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I figured it out.  For contentSize to take effect, I had to uncheck its Superview's "Use Autolayout" property in the File Inspector (within your xib or StoryBoard).